# How can i keep variables state across all activities?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

How can i presist data across all my activities so when I change a variable on activity A, that variable will be changed on all activities to which it belongs.

So to play safe and easier I would like to know the right way to acomplish this.

I read some ppl sayng to use static variable but I have like 45-70 variables and 21 classes and doenst feels right to me to just put everything static...

I have also been using intents to pass the data between activities but I have to update it manually all the time wich can lead to inconsistencies sometimes.

My goal is to have a class that can be shared between all activities automatically and replicate any changes across all activities.

Comment: 1. You can use shared Preferences to store the variables.
2. You can use LiveData from room library.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for here is a model object. <s>Android has a [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) object that would work well for this. The `ViewModel` object should be able to outlive the lifecycle of any activities or fragments that use it. I would recommend checking out that link as it will likely explain how to use a `ViewModel` more thoroughly than I ever could.</s>

Edit: I misunderstood some parts of your question. Using a static class like you mentioned is definitely an option (and in my opinion, not an anti-pattern). If you would like to persist that data across app restarts, you could also utilize Room.

On a side note, I would also recommend using [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) inside your model. `LiveData` is a wrapper of sorts that makes practically any object observable. You'll be able to observe your data in your model object and notify activities that need to know accordingly.

Comment: i appreciate your answer, but OP specifically says he is using `Activities`...

Comment: @a_local_nobody He's asking how to persist data across Activities. He never said that he wanted to *use* an activity to do that. In fact he almost explicitly mentions that he wants to create a class to be shared between the activities (which in essence is a model class). I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at here...

Comment: viewmodel will not work for different activities

Comment: @a_local_nobody Oops, my bad. My answer more or less should still hold though, just without the use of the actual `ViewModel` object.

Comment: im not trying to argue with you :) just saying that, unless OP changes to fragments, there's no other way to do it except for statics, i agree with you IF IT WAS FRAGMENTS but there's no solution for activities

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yeah for sure, I just misunderstood parts of that question, my bad. That's what I get for speed answering questions during breaks at work... ;)

Comment: happens to the best of us :P will upvote your answer

Comment: I also read that i can Store Objects in ApplicationContext. Would it be worst than using static variables?

Comment: @RyzonPT I don't believe there are any real upsides to storing objects in the Application context. It may just end up adding some unnecessary complexity.